# Android text to speech reader

Tags: android, speech-synthesis, microsoft-edge

Are there any android apps that could read a pdf? The Microsoft Edge browser 
reads a pdf on the windows-10 but I couldn't find a way to open the pdf of android
on Edge. Is there any inbuilt way to read the pdf out loud from android?

Comment: Not tried myself as a) I don't have Play Store access (running Google-free) and b) the app comes with several trackers (AdMob, Firebase etc), but [Voice Aloud Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hyperionics.avar) should be able to read your PDF. Not sure about inside the browser, though.